# Make a button method with Google Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am trying to make a button method to interact with my input text box in Polymer. I want to be able to input text, click the button, and output it to a generic `<div>`.

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<paper-input label="What's on your mind?" id="userText" on-keyup="_onKeyUp"></paper-input>
<paper-button raised class="indigo" on-tap="_onTap"><iron-icon icon="send"></iron-icon></paper-button>
<div id="output1">{{messageText}}</div>
<div id="output1">{{messageText2}}</div>
```

Here is the relevant JavaScript (part of my Polymer constructor object) that is supposed to interact with `_sendMessage2`:

```
_onTap: function (e) {
  if (e.x == 1) {
     this._sendMessage2();
  }
},

_sendMessage2: function () {
  var value2 = this.$.userText.value;
  this.messageText2 = value;
},
```

Comment: Are both the JS functions getting called?

Comment: only _onTap is the one that gets called first, then _onTap calls _sendMessage2

Comment: If you put `console.log(value2);` in the `_sendMessage2()` function does it print when you click the button?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: Well, e.x is not == 1. Console.log(e.x) to take a look at it's value. 
Everything else looks fine to me.

Comment: usually when using events in polymer, I have to find my data in the path `e.detail.x`, not `e.x`

Comment: well of course that `e.x !== 1`.. you would have to click on first pixel from the left of the button to trigger it. And even that would not pass because `e.x` is undefined. It should be `e.detail.x` . Anyway it is nonsense..